# HA registry : how to avoid exception at boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have successfully created 2 registries in HA mode. I followed instructions [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_peer_awareness)  and it's working, but since each registry need the other at boot it throws Exceptions until the two are ready :

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

After a few seconds, each registry connect to each other and everything work fine (each registry has the other as replica), but it's annoying to have those exceptions at boot...

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: maybe you need to start up first the gateway?

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? How the gateway can resolve this ?